# Add expire to Spring Security remember me cookie

Tags: spring, tomcat, cookies, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2 (with embedded Tomcat), Spring MVC 4.3.4  and Spring Security 4.1.3  to build a simple website. My login page contains a remember me Checkbox, which toggles whether or not a remember me cookie is created by Spring Security.

This cookie is set perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox, but as IE and MS Edge do not use the `Max-Age` attribute those only create a session cookie. Is there a way to have Spring Security (additionally to `Max-Age`) set the `Expire` attribute on the `Set-Cookie` header for the remember me cookie?

Below is my Spring Security configuration:

```java
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/private/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
        .rememberMe()
            .tokenValiditySeconds(365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional to [`Max-Age`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.2) you can also add [`Expires`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.1) attribute.

The configuration is part of the container, see [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/cookie-processor.html#Standard_Implementation):

> alwaysAddExpires
>
> If this is `true` Tomcat will always add an expires parameter to a SetCookie header even for cookies with version greater than zero. This is to work around a known IE6 and IE7 bug that causes I to ignore the Max-Age parameter in a SetCookie header.
>
> If `org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE` is set to true, the default of this setting will be false, else the default value will be true.

But there is no [Common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for `Expires` in Spring Boot. So you have to change the [`CookieProcessor`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/CookieProcessor.html) to [`LegacyCookieProcessor`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/LegacyCookieProcessor.html) and configure it, see [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-legacycookieprocessor):

> **70.10 Use Tomcat’s LegacyCookieProcessor**
>
> The embedded Tomcat used by Spring Boot does not support "Version 0" of the Cookie format out of the box, and you may see the following error:
>
> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [32] was present in the Cookie value
> ```
>
> If at all possible, you should consider updating your code to only store values compliant with later Cookie specifications. If, however, you’re unable to change the way that cookies are written, you can instead configure Tomcat to use a  `LegacyCookieProcessor`. To switch to the `LegacyCookieProcessor` use an `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` bean that adds a `TomcatContextCustomizer`:
>
> ```java
> @Bean
> public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer cookieProcessorCustomizer() {
>     return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
>             if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
>                 ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
>                        .addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
>
>                     @Override
>                     public void customize(Context context) {
>                        context.setCookieProcessor(new LegacyCookieProcessor());
>                     }
>
>                 });
>             }
>         }
>    };
> }
> ```